# c#, cannot DeSerialize XMl file

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I need to send a request to the web service. this request asks for a "session" object as parameter.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18060")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.xmlns.cfins.com/cfins/services/publishPolicyData/1.0")]
public partial class session {

    private object[] itemsField;

    private string idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("data", typeof(sessionData))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("properties", typeof(sessionProperties))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string id {
        get {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

here's my xml file.

```
    <session id="6055">
      <properties dateModified="2014-01-08" engineVersion="2.0" cultureCode="en-US" cultureName="United States [english]">
        <userName>admin</userName>
      </properties>
      <data id="d2311A049FDC64CD9AE9EF3DE5874CB2D">
        .....
      </data>
    </session>
```

when I deserialize this xml file,  I only get id, items is alway null. BTW, the session class is from web service, I cannot change it.

```
    public static session GetSession()
    {
        var s = new session();
        var data = new sessionData();

        var sessionXml = @"C:\Projects\CFWinSvc - Copy\XmlDeSerialize\session.xml";

        using (TextReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(sessionXml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(session));
            s = (session)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return s;

    }


    public static session GetSession()
    {
        var s = new session();
        var data = new sessionData();


        var sessionXml = @"C:\Projects\CFWinSvc - Copy\XmlDeSerialize\session.xml";

        using (TextReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(sessionXml))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(session));
            s = (session)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return s;

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

here's the XML Schema.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.cfins.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.xmlns.cfins.com/cfins/services/publishPolicyData/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:element name="session">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="properties">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="userName" type="xs:string"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                                <xs:attribute name="dateModified" use="optional"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="engineVersion" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="cultureCode" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="cultureName" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="data">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="AlwaysAddIDs" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="ProRatingOn" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    <xs:element name="carrier" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="userinterface" minOccurs="0">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:all>
                                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your session class.
However, it is marked as

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.xmlns.cfins.com/cfins/services/publishPolicyData/1.0")]
```

which pretty much means that xml deserializer will only consider sub-elements of your `session` that are in the same xml namespace.

In short, adding ugly namespace definitions to your xml file like so:

```
<properties xmlns="http://www.xmlns.cfins.com/cfins/services/publishPolicyData/1.0" ...
```

will do the trick: you'll get all your sessionProperties and sessionData where needed.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlElement` should not be used for collection or array properties. `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` should be used instead. I don't know why the code would be generated like you show above. Did you modify it after it was generated? If you share your schema, maybe we can identify the issue with the codegen.

```
[XmlArray]
[XmlArrayItem("data", typeof(sessionData))]
[XmlArrayItem("properties", typeof(sessionProperties))]
public object[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: another developer loads the xml to Visual studio. choose xml from the top menu, then choose create schema.

Comment: test it one more time, i am able to generate schema using visual studio. however if i use xsd.exe, i got this error message. "Error: There was an error processing 'QASession.xml'.
  - Cannot add a nested relation or an element column to a table containing a SimpleContent column."

Comment: Are you generating the schema from XML, and then generating code from the schema? Or are you creating the schema by hand and then generating the code? Please describe your process more clearly.

Comment: not manually, we are using visual studio to generate that schema. loads the xml to Visual studio. choose xml from the top menu, then choose create schema.  I just test it using another tool "xsd.exe", this time, xsd gave me error. see above comment.  but visual studio didnt have any issue to generate schema.  btw, the xml file i posted here is trimmed version. the full version is about 2k lines, too big to post it here.

Comment: see my last commnet, I edit the comment and post the details there.

Comment: So the code in the first block of your original post (that's the code I've been asking about) is generated via a Service Reference? If that's the case, you've uncovered a bug in the code generation tool. You'll need to manually edit the generated code as per my answer. You may also need to add `Namespace="http://www.cfins.com"` to the `XmlArrayItem`s.

Comment: thank you so much, i will try it after i get back home.

Answer (score 0):

To use Xml Serialization, all your attribute need to have a public getter and setter, else the reflector while refuse to serialize or deserialize your object.